# How can I find information on a nineteenth century marriage in Denmark?

Tags: 19th-century, marriage-records, denmark

My grandmother was Inger Marie Larsen (Pedersen).  She lived in Norresundby, Denmark in 1883 when my father was born.  Her husband was Christian Jensen ( a Gardner) from Hellum, Denmark.  I'm looking for their marriage.  (My grandmother was Inger Marie Larsen her father was Lars Christian Pederson.  Her married name was Jensen.)

The only information I have is baptism from NorreSundby churchbooks 1884 that shows my father's Baptism with his parents names and his birth was November 11, 1883.  I also have a copy of their emigration paperwork to leave Copenhagen on April 29,1884 to Boston.  I have not found them arriving.

I have checked family search and ancestry, plus Archivalieronline.

Comment: Hello Charlotte, and welcome. It would be helpful for you to tell us what you've already tried/where you've looked to find the marriage, so that we don't suggest things you've already tried.

Comment: There's an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to add the information.

Comment: What is meant by the round brackets in your grandmother's name?  Was Inger Marie Larsen Pedersen her full name prior to marriage or is something else meant?  Have you obtained a birth certificate/record for your father?  If so, what information does it contain about his parents?

Comment: @PolyGeo [Scandinavian family name etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_family_name_etymology)

Comment: There are extensive digitized collections on Danish genealogy available on Archivalieronline, FamilySearch an Ancestry.com. Have you checked these collections for marriages in Nørresundby before 1884?

Comment: I have checked family search and ancestry,  plus Archivalieronline.  Thanks lejonet

Answer (score 7):

First, have your looked in Nørresundby Kirkebøger (churchbooks) for their marriage (Viede)? Was your father a first child? Or were there older children? That has a bearing on your timeline. (Consider looking for a marriage date up to and including 1884.) Looking in Nørresundby would be the obvious first step. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get into Statens Arkiver https://www2.sa.dk/ for the last couple of weeks or I would look for you.

I use the Family History Library catalog search as my gazetteer and I see only one Nørresundby in Aalborg amt (county). I determined it was in Kaer herred (district) by searching a map of Aalborg jurisdictions at http://www.danishfamilysearch.dk/amt2. However, when I search for Hellum, I see that it is both a herred in Aalborg amt and a sogn (parish) in Hjørring amt, the county just north of Aalborg amt. I suspect you mean Hellum sogn. If so, it is in Dronninglund herred, the herred nextto Aalborg boundaries. See the map of Hjørring jurisdictions: http://www.danishfamilysearch.dk/amt9. If I'm being tedious about this, it's because you must have the right place to find anything specific and also that different records are held at different levels of jurisdiction.

Typically in a settled society, the marriage takes place in the bride's church. Have you looked for your grandmother's family in Nørresundby? If you cannot find them there, you might be able to determine when your grandparents arrived in Nørresundby. I see that the Family History Library has Til and Afgangslister (arrival and departure lists) for Nørresundby only up until 1875. That might be useful for an earlier arrival.

If your grandfather came from Hellum sogn in Hjørring, you can search online both at Statens  Arkiver and at FamilySearch https://familysearch.org/search/collection/2078555 by selecting Browse and drilling down by amt, herred, to the Hellum sogn and a listing of available records. You are in luck if your father was born no earlier than 1855. You can look for birth records (Fødte) in Volume 13 (1855-1875). Otherwise, there appears to be a gap in this record set that I have verified exists also at Danish Family Search www.danishfamilysearch.dk.

Be very careful in identifying persons by name. If you have your grandfather's birth date or the names of his parents, you can ensure that you have the right person. Remember that the records are in Scandinavian Gothic script. For help, see Denmark Handwriting https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Denmark_Handwriting. For words you'll encounter, see Genealogical Words in Danish Research https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Category:Genealogical_Words_in_Danish_Research

For triangulation, you should look for your grandparents or their families in the 1880 census. The Folketaelling (census) for Hjørring amt is available online -- when it works -- at Statens Arkiver.  https://www2.sa.dk. You must know the herred as well as the sogn. Use the same procedure for Aalborg amt.

Good luck.

Comment: I would like to further emphasize one point here, ***"Typically in a settled society, the marriage takes place in the bride's church."***  Be sure of where the bride lived and participated in church and then look there for the marriage record there.